# TypeError: Prismic.getApi is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

i'm really struggling while trying to build a website from scratch without a framework. And now i'm integrating Prismic in through node.js, but as I'm following all the passages i'm getting stuck by this error shown in the log of the terminal: TypeError: Prismic.getApi is not a function.

As a consequence of this i can see the local website but the about link doesn't load. How can i fix that?

This is the main code related to the package.json

```
require('dotenv').config()

console.log(process.env.PRISMIC_ENDPOINT, process.env.PRISMIC_CLIENT_ID)

const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const path = require('path')
const port = 3000

const Prismic = require('@prismicio/client')
const PrismicDOM = require('prismic-dom')

const initApi = req => {
  return Prismic.getApi(process.env.PRISMIC_ENDPOINT, {
    accessToken: process.env.PRISMIC_ACCESS_TOKEN,
    req
  })
}
const handlelinkResolver = doc => {
// Define the url depending on the document type
// if (doc.type === 'page'){
//  return '/page/' + doc.uid;
// } else if (doc.type === 'blog_post'){
//  return '/blog/' + doc.uid;
//  }
// Default to homepage
  return '/'
}

app.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.locals.ctx = {
    endpoint: process.env.PRISMIC_ENDPOINT,
    linkResolver: handlelinkResolver
  }

  res.locals.PrismicDOM = PrismicDOM

  next()
})

app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'))
app.set('view engine', 'pug')

app.get('/', async (req, res) => {
  res.render('pages/home')
})

app.get('/about', async (req, res) => {
  initApi(req).then((api) => {
    api.query(
      Prismic.Predicates.at('document.type', 'about')
    ).then(response => {
      console.log(response)
      res.render('pages/about')
    })
  })
})

app.get('/personaggi', (req, res) => {
  res.render('pages/personaggi')
})

app.get('/detail/:uid', (req, res) => {
  res.render('pages/detail')
})

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Example app listening on port ${port}`)
})
```

Comment: If you are using version 6, getApi is no longer present in the instance.

Replace all client creation methods with createClient(). All other methods of creating a client, including client(), getApi(), and api(), have been replaced by the single createClient() function.

Comment: Thank you for the response, so if I've understood correctly I have to change getApi with createClient () without installing anything else?

Comment: I have done what you said and now i have another error: A valid fetch implementation was not provided. In environments where fetch is not available (including Node.js), a fetch implementation must be provided via a polyfill or the `fetch` option. 
Do i have to create a polyfill file or something?

Answer (score 0):

You can use :

```js
const Prismic = require('prismic-javascript')

// NB : This package has been deprecated but it's still working.
```

Instead of :

```js
const Prismic = require('@prismicio/client')
```

OR you can use the actual setup guide of Prismic at https://prismic.io/docs/technologies/express-install

Answer (score 0):

As user bmz1 mentionned, `getApi()` is no longer used in version 6+. Downgrade `@prismicio/client`.

In your package.json dependencies, replace by :

```
"@prismicio/client": "5.1.0"
```

Don't forget to run `npm i` to reset your dependencies